# Is the arctan of a negative number always negative?

Tags: trigonometry

Is the $\text{ arctan}$ of a negative number always negative and $\text{ arctan}$ of a positve number always positive ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\arctan\left(0\right)=0,\, \frac{d}{dx}\arctan\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}>0. $$

Answer (score 0):

**True**. If $\tan^{-1} x = \theta \Rightarrow x = \tan \theta$ and $\theta \in \left(-\pi/2,\pi/2\right)$. Thus if $x < 0$, then $\theta < 0$, and the same is true for the positive case.

Comment: if θ is negative, is tanθ always negative?  

I mean : is tan(-θ) = -tanθ always?

Comment: Not necessarily true. Take $\theta = -\dfrac{3\pi}{4}, \tan(\theta) = 1 > 0$, but it is true that $\tan(-\theta) = -\tan(\theta), \forall \theta $